# Acronyms package - sort acronyms alphabetical order ShareLatex

Tags: acronyms, sorting

I'm using:

```
\begin{acronym}
\acro{URL}{Uniform Resource Locator}
\end{acronym}
```

with package `\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}`

But my acronyms are not alphabetical sorted , and I want it. How can I make this?

Comment: Is there sorting at all in `acronym`?

Comment: The `acronym` package does not support this AFAIK. You have to do it manually.

Comment: @clemens: Does your `acro` package support sorting?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes. (And of course `glossaries` and IIRC also `nomencl`)

Comment: @clemens: Then go ahead, grab the rep ;-)

Comment: There is any way to don't make manually ? @ChristianHupfer

Comment: @PRVS: The manual of `acronym` does not say anything about sorting -- I would say 'no' :-(

Comment: @PRVS maybe your editor can do it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199337/alphabetizing-a-customized-list-of-abbreviations#comment462915_199337

Comment: i'm with sharelatex only, non exists solution in this posts.

Comment: @PRVS if you have an editor capable of sorting you could copy the list in said editor, let it sort the lines, and then copy the list back to sharelatex. Otherwise your choices are manual sorting or switching packages (the first is probably a lot less work)

Comment: I can switch package but which?
I don't have an editor capable of sorting